# Multiple Ultrasonic Sensor with Raspberry Pİ

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors, arduino-ultra-sonic

I am new in here and in programming. I have problem about multiple ultrasonic sensor using on raspberry pi. I am making an autonomous car (kind of :)). I had one sensor before just for the front I wanted to put two more on the corners and I am trying  that two sensor working together.

I have problems with codding (I can't say I have very knowledge about python I am new one), some how I worked the cod but sensors do not work properly they measure wrong and one of them doesn't work at all

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
def main():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    TRIG = 40
    ECHO = 38
    TRIG1 = 31
    ECHO1 = 29



    Motor1A = 16
    Motor1B = 18
    Motor1E = 22

    Motor2A = 13
    Motor2B = 11
    Motor2E = 15

    GPIO.setup(TRIG, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(ECHO, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(TRIG1, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(ECHO1, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(Motor1A, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(Motor1B, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(Motor1E, GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.setup(Motor2A, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(Motor2B, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(Motor2E, GPIO.OUT)




    camera = PiCamera()
    camera.resolution =(640, 480)
    camera.framerate =32
    rawCapture=PiRGBArray(camera,size=(640,480))

    time.sleep(0.1)



    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):

        GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
        time.sleep(0.05)
        GPIO.output(TRIG1, False)
        time.sleep(0.05)

        GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
        time.sleep(0.00001)
        GPIO.output(TRIG1, True)
        time.sleep(0.00001)
        GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
        GPIO.output(TRIG1, False)

        while GPIO.input(ECHO, ECHO1) == 1:
            pulse_start = time.time()

        while GPIO.input(ECHO, ECHO1) == 1:
            pulse_end = time.time()

        pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start

        distance = pulse_duration * 17150

        distance = round(distance, 2)

        print("Mesafe:", distance - 0.5, "cm")

        if distance < 20:
            print ("Mesafe:", distance - 0.5, "cm Engel algilandi")
            GPIO.output(Motor1A, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(Motor1B, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(Motor1E, GPIO.HIGH)

            GPIO.output(Motor2A, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(Motor2B, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(Motor2E, GPIO.HIGH)



        else:
            print("Mesafe:", distance - 0.5, "cm")
            GPIO.output(Motor1A, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(Motor1B, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(Motor1E, GPIO.HIGH)

            GPIO.output(Motor2A, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(Motor2B, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(Motor2E, GPIO.HIGH)




        imgOriginal = frame.array

        imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(imgOriginal, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        imgThreshLow = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, np.array([0, 70, 50]), np.array([10, 255, 255]))
        imgThreshHigh = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, np.array([170, 70, 50]), np.array([180, 255, 255]))
        imgThresh = cv2.add(imgThreshLow, imgThreshHigh)
        imgThresh = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgThresh, (3, 3), 2)
        imgThresh = cv2.dilate(imgThresh, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8))
        imgThresh = cv2.erode(imgThresh, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8))
        intRows, intColums = imgThresh.shape
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(imgThresh,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,5,intRows/4)
        if circles is not None:

            print("kirmizi tabela algilandi.Dikkat !")


            for circle in circles[0]:
                x, y, radius = circle
                print("pozisyon x = " + str(x) + ", y = " + str(y) + ", radius = " + str(radius))
                cv2.circle(imgOriginal, (x, y), 3, (0, 255, 0), -1)
                cv2.circle(imgOriginal, (x, y), radius, (0, 0, 255), 3)
            #end for
        #end if

        else:
            print("yol serbest")


        cv2.imshow("Frame", imgOriginal)
        cv2.imshow("imgThresh",imgThresh)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        rawCapture.truncate(0)

        if key == ord("q"):
            return


if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: some cods are about pi camera never mind them but I can say cod was working properly when I was using just one sensor

Comment: Can you post the working code with only one sensor? Also, did you check if each sensor is working individually with the working code? You shouldn't combine ultrasonic sensors echo signals the way you are doing (each sensor would have different echo timing and hence read different distances). You should measure the distance from each sensor individually, and then make a final decision based on all the distances read.

Comment: One more thing, you also need to be careful that the ultrasonic sensors are not interfering with each other. The speed of sound is 340m/s or roughly 34.300cm/ms. So each 1ms error would result in a 34.300cm error in the reading. I am not sure about the timing precision on the python but it is better to reduce the chance of error due to reflection from a different ultrasonic sensor so ideally, you should isolate them, either physically or by sampling them one at a time.

Comment: I checked each sensors work individually with working code but I can not combine them. I understood what you mean but I thought also this solution but I could not crate a code like you said. Can u help me ? By the way I validated sensor measuring there are some import code that make it right .

Comment: And I am not sure about isolating I said I am very new and searching right now. I will consider that.

Comment: Isolating the sensor means avoiding the crosstalk between sensors. It can be achieved either by mounting the sensor in different directions or making sure their fields of view do not intersect. A normal HCSR-04 ultrasonic sensor has an effectual angle of 15 degrees which means it can detect reflections from an object positioned up to 15 deg from the centre of the sensor. You can achieve isolation either by physically placing the sensors to they don't interfere with each other or firing only one sensor at a time. If the max range of the sensor is 4m, you can set the sample period at least 12ms

Comment: This link has useful info on using multiple ultrasonic sensors and crosstalk https://www.maxbotix.com/tutorials1/031-using-multiple-ultrasonic-sensors.htm